# Same query returns different values on repeated execution

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7, mysql-5.6, mysql5

**Database in use**: 5.6 (I can't use LAG function which is from mysql 8)

I have the following table structure in mysql

```
book_id     | Version      | Rating | Price 
varchar(25) | Decimal(10,2)| int    | Decimal(10,2)
```

I have a web page where I show two charts.

In first chart, I will show count of books for rating(ratings are only from 1 to 4) but only of the latest versions. `Query1`

In second chart, I will show count of books in a price range but only of the latest versions. `Query2`

These two queries are ran one after the other every time the web page is loaded or refreshed. Although data remains constant, I get different results sometimes for the same query.

I have the following two queries which are almost identical

**QUERY1**

```
SELECT  
       SUM(CASE WHEN rating=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS rating1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rating=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS rating2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rating=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS rating3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rating=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS rating4
FROM (
       SELECT rating, row_number
       FROM (
              SELECT rating, 
                     @num:=IF(@group:=book_id, @num+1, 1) row_number,
                     @group:=book_id bi
              FROM book_database
              ORDER BY book_id, version DESC
             ) book
      HAVING book.row_number = 1
    ) book
```

**QUERY2**

```
SELECT  
       SUM(CASE WHEN price <= 1000 THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS cheap,
       SUM(CASE WHEN price >1000 THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS costly
FROM (
       SELECT price, row_number
       FROM (
              SELECT price, 
                     @num:=IF(@group:=book_id, @num+1, 1) row_number,
                     @group:=book_id bi
              FROM book_database
              ORDER BY book_id, version DESC
             ) book
      HAVING book.row_number = 1
    ) book
```

There are multiple screens in my webpage and with multiple queries but most of them work on same logic. Basically I will query on latest version of any book, and hence I use the nested query.

On some occasions I get different results than intended when same queries ran multiple times on same dataset.

*Is my query correct?
Is usage of variables causing this issue?
Since multiple queries are ran in parallel (Although in different database connections) usage of variables is the suspect?*

Comment: That is the beauty of using an `ORDER BY` clause in a sub query. MySQL might choose to ignore it when it feels like it!

Comment: can you elaborate

Comment: See https://mysqlserverteam.com/row-numbering-ranking-how-to-use-less-user-variables-in-mysql-queries/

Comment: I read through the article... it doesn't apply in this case

Comment: What else would explain getting different results? The point is that a nested order by _could be_ ignored. I suppose you can replace `HAVING` with `WHERE`... this should produce the same result and eliminate unnecessary `GROUP BY` and _might_ produce the correct result.

Comment: Case is, it COULD be ignored but not always. In my case, if I am using MariaDB, it gets ignored. not in mysql. Check out this
https://sujithjay.com/2017/12/01/Order-By-in-From-Subquery-MariaDB-MySQL/

Answer (score 0):

Your use of variables is not correct.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `SELECT` clause, so you should set all the variables at the same time.

For instance, the first query should look something more like this:

```
SELECT SUM( rating = 1 ) AS rating1,
       SUM( rating = 2 ) AS rating2,
       SUM( rating = 3 ) AS rating3,
       SUM( rating = 4 ) AS rating4
FROM (SELECT rating, book_id,
             (@rn := if(@b = book_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@b := book_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      FROM (SELECT rating, book_id, version
            FROM book_database
            ORDER BY book_id, version DESC
           ) book CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0, @b := -1) params
    ) book
WHERE rn = 1;
```

The important part is the part that involves the variables.  I also simplified some of the other logic.

But, you don't need variables for this:

```
SELECT SUM( rating = 1 ) AS rating1,
       SUM( rating = 2 ) AS rating2,
       SUM( rating = 3 ) AS rating3,
       SUM( rating = 4 ) AS rating4
FROM book_database b
WHERE b.version = (SELECT MAX(b2.version)
                   FROM book_database b2
                   WHERE b2.book_id = b.book_id
                  );
```

With an index on `book_database(book_id, version)`, this should be faster than the version using variables.